# Union of family of topology is a subbasis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For any family $(\tau_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ of topologies on a set X, How do we show the fact  that $\cup_{\alpha\in A} \tau_\alpha$ is a subbasis for a topology on X that is stronger than all the $\tau_\alpha$'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

This should be quite doable definition unpacking.  You need to show that resulting topology is stronger (I think that has to mean finer, which I find more usual terminology).  That means, literally, that open set topology of coarser topology is contained in finer.  So, take an open set from any topology in given family and prove it's in the topology generated by the union.  That should amount to showing it's intersection and union of something.. and that's it, really.

Comment: Thanks! But I have problems showing that it is a sub-basis, do we take an open set O from any arbitrary topology on X and show that there is a element B form the finite intersection of the topologies such that $B \subset O$?

Comment: I don't think you need to show it's sub-basis.  Or rather, given any set $S \subseteq P(X)$ of space $X$, there's just one topology generated by it.  How exactly your material defines the relation between sub-basis and topology might not use generating method (intersection of all topologies containing the sub-basis), but end result is the same.  You seem to be on to something, I think.  Take  topology $\tau_\alpha$ from the family.  Let $T$ be the generated topology.  Show that $\tau_\alpha \subseteq T$, which goes showing it's union of intersections of elements of sub-basis.

Comment: Bleh, many edits above, sorry if you got caught.  I think it's better now, but without giving the full answer, it's hard to say more.  You can do it, just unpack sub-basis to basis to open set.